# Java Swing JTextfield Sizing (Height)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm having some problems getting a JTextfield in my program to the appropriate size, I am trying to amend the textfield with the text 'Price must be a real value'. This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

And this is what mine currently looks like:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
package test1;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test1{

    //Should components be final? Should they be defined outside of the class?
    private final JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
    private final JTextField errorReportField = new JTextField();

    private final JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();

    private final JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Item Name");
    private final JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Number of units (or Volume in L)");
    private final JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price per unit (or L) in pence");

    private final JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private final JTextField numberField = new JTextField(10);
    private final JTextField priceField = new JTextField(10);

    private final JButton addVolumeButton = new JButton("Add by Volume");
    private final JButton addNumberButton = new JButton("Add by number of units");         

    public Test1() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fuel station shop");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        outputArea.setRows(30);
        JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        errorReportField.setEditable(false);

        //Better way of adding multiple components to panel?
        inputPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        inputPanel.add(nameLabel);
        inputPanel.add(nameField);
        inputPanel.add(numberLabel);
        inputPanel.add(numberField);
        inputPanel.add(priceLabel);
        inputPanel.add(priceField);
        inputPanel.add(addVolumeButton);
        inputPanel.add(addNumberButton);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        //Why is it adding components from bottom to top?
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.add(scrollPanel);
        contentPane.add(errorReportField);
        contentPane.add(inputPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test = new Test1();
    }

}
```

So basically I would like to increase the height of the textfield while keeping the text centered, as well as changing the background to white while keeping it non-editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BorderLayout` instead of `BoxLayout`.

Put the text area at `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and wrap the text field and the bottom panel in another panel with `GridLayout(0, 1)`. Add that panel to `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. The text field will be the same size as that bottom panel

**Aside**

- Swing application should be run/started on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- For general information on layout managers, see [Layout Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- Also not sure why your field and text are are not editable.

---

Refactor

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test1{

    //Should components be final? Should they be defined outside of the class?
    private final JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
    private final JTextField errorReportField = new JTextField();

    private final JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();

    private final JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Item Name");
    private final JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Number of units (or Volume in L)");
    private final JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price per unit (or L) in pence");

    private final JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private final JTextField numberField = new JTextField(10);
    private final JTextField priceField = new JTextField(10);

    private final JButton addVolumeButton = new JButton("Add by Volume");
    private final JButton addNumberButton = new JButton("Add by number of units");         

    public Test1() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fuel station shop");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //outputArea.setEditable(false);
        outputArea.setRows(30);
        JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        //errorReportField.setEditable(false);

        //Better way of adding multiple components to panel?
        inputPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        inputPanel.add(nameLabel);
        inputPanel.add(nameField);
        inputPanel.add(numberLabel);
        inputPanel.add(numberField);
        inputPanel.add(priceLabel);
        inputPanel.add(priceField);
        inputPanel.add(addVolumeButton);
        inputPanel.add(addNumberButton);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        //Why is it adding components from bottom to top?
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(scrollPanel);
        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        wrapper.add(errorReportField);
        wrapper.add(inputPanel);
        contentPane.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Test1 test = new Test1();
            }
        });  
    }
}
```

---

**Note**

If you want the field a little bigger (height-wise), you can add an empty border to the `inputPanel`, causing the field to expand also. But this would mean that the `inputPanel` will be a little bigger also (may or may not be desired). But either way, with the GridLayout, the field and the `inputPanel` will be the same size.

```
inputPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
```

Another option would be to give the `wrapper` panel a `BorderLayout` and add the field to the center, giving it an `EmptyBorder` to expand its size.

```
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(scrollPanel);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
wrapper.add(errorReportField);
wrapper.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

Border border = errorReportField.getBorder();
CompoundBorder compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        border,BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
errorReportField.setBorder(compound);

contentPane.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

This will give a slight margin on the left of the field (which may or may not be desireable). If you don't want it, just change the values for the empty border.

```
createEmptyBorder(top, left, bottom, right)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want increase field's height, modify its preffered size (apply method to your field):

```
private void increaseFieldHeight(JTextField field, int times) {
    Dimension d = field.getPreferredSize();
    d.height = d.height * times;
    field.setPreferredSize(d);
}
```